# Using certificates in native code in Android

Tags: android, openssl, android-ndk

I am trying to load certificates in my JNI code for my android application. Has anyone tried something similar to this? I know that Open-SSL has functions that require require the certificate file. I found out that you can store the certificate in memory in this manner. I need this functionality as I want to hard code the certificates. Right now this code snippet is supposed to do that job but it doesn't.

```
BIO* mem_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(certificate, strlen(certificate));
X509* cert = PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(mem_bio,NULL,NULL,NULL);
X509_STORE_add_cert(ctx->cert_store,cert);
BIO_free(mem_bio);
X509_free(cert);
(ctx is a handle to my SSL_CTX)
```

I am fairly new to C programming, Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its a silly mistake. The shared library that I was trying to build was not linking properly with the libssl.a and libcrypto.a static libraries that I was using.

I figured this out after looking at output form "nm" command 
      nm 
 and it showed that all the functions that were provided by these two static libraries as Undefined.